# How To calculate the average value in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to calculate the average values as following .

```
${var1}= 10
${var2}= 50
${var3}= 10
${var4}= 30
${var5}= 50
```

Executed
average is 30

How should writing syntax used?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Evaluate`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) from [BuiltIn library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html)

```
${Average}=     Evaluate       (${var1}+${var2}+${var3}+${var4}+${var5})/5
```

Output -

[image]